# Add column with previous date (not equal current date)[SQL, PrestoDB]

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table like this:

| current_date | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 1 |
| 2021-10-02 | 1 |
| 2021-10-02 | 1 |
| 2021-10-09 | 1 |
| 2021-10-15 | 1 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 |
| 2021-10-11 | 2 |
| 2021-10-11 | 2 |

I want to add one more column with previous date (not equal current date).

Desired table should looks like this:

| current_date | user_id | previous_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 | 1 |  |
| 2021-10-02 | 1 | 2021-10-01 |
| 2021-10-02 | 1 | 2021-10-01 |
| 2021-10-09 | 1 | 2021-10-02 |
| 2021-10-15 | 1 | 2021-10-09 |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 |  |
| 2021-10-01 | 2 |  |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 | 2021-10-01 |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 | 2021-10-01 |
| 2021-10-04 | 2 | 2021-10-01 |
| 2021-10-11 | 2 | 2021-10-04 |
| 2021-10-11 | 2 | 2021-10-04 |

Thanks for your help!

Comment: you need to use `lag()` function to achieve this.

Comment: @MoulitharanM yeah) but how avoid doubled dates?

Comment: you have to take distinct value and then perform lag, join the result set with the original dataset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a join along with the `LAG` function, we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(current_date) OVER
                  (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY current_date) previous_date
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT current_date, user_id FROM yourTable) t
)

SELECT t1.current_date, t1.user_id, t2.previous_date
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id AND t2.current_date = t1.current_date
ORDER BY t1.user_id, t1.current_date;
```

Here is a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f04030d81043c7cc051ac55718448779) in SQL Server, though the same query should run in Presto with minimal modifications needed.